# ros3djs Arrow on SceneNode not moving with TF frame

Tags: ros, ros3djs, robotwebtools

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to visualise the movements of TF frame using the Robot Web Tools I have a robot localising using amcl and I want to move an arrow along with one of its TF frames (base_link). According to my understanding of the tutorials, the code below should do this. However, instead the arrow is drawn at the origin of the fixed frame and doesn't move. I am using ROS Groovy plus the current CDN versions of the Robot Web Tools. Am I doing something wrong, or is there a bug stopping the expected behaviour?

```
  // Create the scene manager and view port for the 3D world.
  var viewer3D = new ROS3D.Viewer({
    divID      : 'threed-map',
    width      : 560,
    height     : 420,
    antialias  : true,
    background : '#EEEEEE'
  });

  // Create a TF client that subscribes to the fixed frame.
  var tfClient = new ROSLIB.TFClient({
    ros          : ros,
    angularThres : 0.01,
    transThres   : 0.01,
    rate         : 10.0,
    fixedFrame   : '/map'
  });
  
  var arrowNode = new ROS3D.SceneNode({
    tfClient : tfClient,
    frameID  : '/base_link',
    object   : new ROS3D.Arrow(),        
  });

  viewer3D.scene.add(arrowNode);
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66107/ros3djs-arrow-on-scenenode-not-moving-with-tf-frame/) by [hawesie](https://answers.ros.org/users/246/hawesie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 282 on 2013-06-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to get your example to work (using turtlesim) without any problems. Here is what I ran:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="http://cdn.robotwebtools.org/threejs/current/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.robotwebtools.org/ColladaAnimationCompress/0.0.1/ColladaLoader2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.robotwebtools.org/EventEmitter2/current/eventemitter2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.robotwebtools.org/roslibjs/current/roslib.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.robotwebtools.org/ros3djs/current/ros3d.js"></script>

<script>
  function init() {
    var ros = new ROSLIB.Ros({
      url : 'ws://localhost:9090'
    });

     var viewer3D = new ROS3D.Viewer({
      divID      : 'threed-map',
      width      : 560,
      height     : 420,
      antialias  : true,
      background : '#111111'
    });

    // Create a TF client that subscribes to the fixed frame.
    var tfClient = new ROSLIB.TFClient({
      ros          : ros,
      angularThres : 0.01,
      transThres   : 0.01,
      rate         : 10.0,
      fixedFrame   : '/world'
    });

    var arrowNode = new ROS3D.SceneNode({
      tfClient : tfClient,
      frameID  : '/turtle1',
      object   : new ROS3D.Arrow(),        
    });

    viewer3D.scene.add(arrowNode);
  }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="init()">
  <div id="threed-map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

After this, I ran the following commands:

```
roslaunch turtle_tf turtle_tf_demo.launch
rosrun tf2_web_republisher tf2_web_republisher
roslaunch rosbridge_server rosbridge_websocket.launch
```

Use your arrow keys on your keyboard to move the turtle (you must have `turtle_tf_demo.launch` terminal focused).

Make sure `tf2_web_republisher` is up and running before your connect. Also, check to see if results are being sent back to the client:

```
rostopic echo /tf2_web_republisher/feedback
```

---

Originally posted by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) with karma: 1173 on 2013-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hawesie](https://answers.ros.org/users/246/hawesie/) on 2013-06-27**:
Thanks for all your help today! Somehow `tf2_web_republisher` had fallen out of my launch file in some git merges. I was seeing the subscriptions popping up in rosbridge, but didn't twig that no-one was publishing on them. Putting it back in fixed this.